# Checking pairs of items between two data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by

I have 2 data frames (A and B) of the following structure:

A:

```
projectID    offerID
   20          12
   20          17 
   32          12
   32          25
```

B:

```
 projectID    offerID
   20          12
   20          17 
   32          12
```

and I'd like to check for pairs that are in A but not in B. So in my example, I'd like to get new df which contains the pairs that are in A but not in B:

```
projectID    offerID
   32           25
```

I tried some options; for example:

```
APairs <- A %>% group_by(projectID, offerID)
BPairs <- B %>% group_by(projectID, offerID)

!(APairs %in% BPairs)
```

but I'm getting True/False result, which I can't really understand/verify against my data.

Your help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `anti_join` from `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 anti_join(A, B)
 #    projectID offerID
 #1        32      25
```

If there are more number of columns, specify the `by` option

```
 anti_join(A, B, by = c("projectID", "offerID"))
 #    projectID offerID
 #1        32      25
```

Answer (score 4):

In `base` R:

```
#define the key columns in the case of different structure between A and B
cols<-c("projectID","offerID")
A[!do.call(paste,A[cols]) %in% do.call(paste,B[cols]),]
#  projectID offerID
#4        32      25
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(A))
setkey(setDT(B))
A[!B]                # A[B] is similar to merge() so perform the opposite using !
#   projectID offerID
#1:        32      25

#incase there are extra columns in any of the table, the specify the common columns in a vector
common.col <- c("projectID", "offerID")
setkeyv(setDT(A), cols = common.col)
setkeyv(setDT(B), cols = common.col)
A[!B]
```

Comment: It doesn't work for some reason. you think it's because I have more columns in one of the data frames?

Comment: @staove7 i have edited based on your new query to having extra columns! let me know how this performs!

Comment: it tells me that x is not a data.table.. :(

Comment: have the `setDT()` around the `A/B` @staove7

Comment: You don't really need to set keys. It is better on use `on` which does not sort the data.